# Creacion de varios objetos en Canvas HTML5 con angular

Tags: html5, angular, typescript, canvas

Adapté un ejemplo de canvas de javascript a typescript en angular, donde creo los objetos utilizando la clase *Circle* en la función `iniciar()` tal como se muestra líneas abajo:

```
iniciar(){
    ...
    let my_circle= new Circle(random_x,random_y,50,"black","hola",5,this.window_height!,this.window_width!,this.context,this.hit_counter!);
    let my_circle2= new Circle(random_x2,random_y2,50,"black","hola",5,this.window_height!,this.window_width!,this.context,this.hit_counter!);
    
    my_circle.draw(this.context);
    my_circle2.draw(this.context);
    ...
}
```

Pero cuando se genera el desplazamiento de estos círculos en el canvas, en la parte de actualización del objeto solo me muestra un solo objeto círculo y no los dos que se habían creado.

```
let updateCircle=function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(updateCircle);
      my_circle.update();
      my_circle2.update();
}
```

Adjunto código completo.

```
export class CirculosComponent implements OnInit {
  canvas:any;
  context:any;
  window_height?:number | undefined;
  window_width?:number | undefined;
  public hit_counter:number | undefined;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.context= this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.window_height=window.innerHeight;
    this.window_width=window.innerWidth;

    this.canvas.width=this.window_width;
    this.canvas.height=this.window_height;
    this.canvas.style.background="#ff0";

    this.hit_counter=0;
    this.iniciar();
  }
  iniciar(){
    let random_x= Math.random()*this.window_width!;
    let random_y= Math.random()*this.window_height!;

    let random_x2= Math.random()*this.window_width!;
    let random_y2= Math.random()*this.window_height!;

    let my_circle= new Circle(random_x,random_y,50,"black","hola",5,this.window_height!,this.window_width!,this.context,this.hit_counter!);
    let my_circle2= new Circle(random_x2,random_y2,50,"black","hola",5,this.window_height!,this.window_width!,this.context,this.hit_counter!);

    my_circle.draw(this.context);
    my_circle2.draw(this.context);

    let updateCircle=function(){
      requestAnimationFrame(updateCircle);
      my_circle.update();
      my_circle2.update();
    }
    
    updateCircle();

  }

}

class Circle{
  xpos:number;
  ypos:number;
  radius:number;
  color:number;
  text:string;
  speed:number;
  dx:number;
  dy:number;
  window_width:number;
  window_height:number ;
  context:any;
  hit_counter:number;
  
  constructor(xpos:number,ypos:number,radius:number,color:any,
            text:string,speed:number,window_height:number,window_width:number,
            context:any, hit_counter:number){
      this.xpos=xpos;
      this.ypos=ypos;
      this.radius=radius;
      this.color=color;
      this.text=text;
      this.speed=speed;

      this.window_height=window_height;
      this.window_width=window_width;

      this.context=context;
      this.hit_counter=hit_counter;

      this.dx=1*this.speed;
      this.dy=1*this.speed;
  }

  draw(context:any){
      context.beginPath();

      context.strokeStyle=this.color;
      context.textAlign="center";
      context.textBaseline="middle";
      context.font="20px Arial";
      context.fillText(this.text,this.xpos,this.ypos);
      //context.strokeText(this.text,this.xpos,this.ypos);

      context.lineWidth=5;
      context.arc(this.xpos,this.ypos,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
  }

  update(){
      this.text=String(this.hit_counter);
      this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.window_width,this.window_height);

      this.draw(this.context);

      if((this.xpos+this.radius)>this.window_width!){
          this.dx=-this.dx;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }

      if((this.xpos-this.radius)<0){
          this.dx=-this.dx;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }
      if((this.ypos-this.radius)<0){
          this.dy=-this.dy;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }
      if((this.ypos+this.radius)>this.window_height!){
          this.dy=-this.dy;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }
      this.xpos+=this.dx;
      this.ypos+=this.dy;
  }
}
```

Comment: No será que están sobrepuestos??? porque ambos círculos los inicializas con los mismos valores. Prueba crear un nuevo par de randoms para el circulo 2

Comment: Gracias el comentario, si bien es cierto estaba poniendo las mimas coordenadas,las acabo de cambiar pero aún así me muestra solo un circulo. saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dando respuesta a mi pregunta, sucede que estoy realizando la actualización del objeto  internamente, lo cual hace que todo el canvas se limpie completamente, así que eliminé de la función `update()` del objeto *Circle* la línea a continuación:

```
this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.window_width,this.window_height);
```

y realicé el limpiado del canvas cada vez que los parámetros de mis objetos *Circle* se iban a actualizar en una función separada.

```
 updateCircle(){
   window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.updateCircle());
   this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.window_width,this.window_height);

   this.my_circle.update();
   this.my_circle2.update();
 }
```

Adjunto código completo:

```
export class CirculosComponent implements OnInit {
  canvas:any;
  public context:any;
  window_height?:number | undefined;
  window_width?:number | undefined;
  public hit_counter:number | undefined;
  my_circle:Circle| any;
  my_circle2:Circle| any;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
    this.context= this.canvas.getContext("2d");

    this.window_height=window.innerHeight;
    this.window_width=window.innerWidth;

    this.canvas.width=this.window_width;
    this.canvas.height=this.window_height;
    this.canvas.style.background="#ff0";

    this.hit_counter=0;
    this.iniciar();
  }
  iniciar(){
    let random_x= Math.random()*this.window_width!;
    let random_y= Math.random()*this.window_height!;

    let random_x2= Math.random()*this.window_width!;
    let random_y2= Math.random()*this.window_height!;

    this.my_circle= new Circle(random_x,random_y,50,"black","hola",5,this.window_height!,this.window_width!,this.context,this.hit_counter!);
    this.my_circle2= new Circle(random_x2,random_y2,50,"red","hola",5,this.window_height!,this.window_width!,this.context,this.hit_counter!);


    this.my_circle.draw(this.context);
    this.my_circle2.draw(this.context);
    
    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.updateCircle());
  }
  updateCircle(){
   window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this.updateCircle());
    this.context.clearRect(0,0,this.window_width,this.window_height);

    this.my_circle.update();
    this.my_circle2.update();
  }

}


class Circle{
  xpos:number;
  ypos:number;
  radius:number;
  color:number;
  text:string;
  speed:number;
  dx:number;
  dy:number;
  window_width:number;
  window_height:number ;
  context:any;
  hit_counter:number;
  
  constructor(xpos:number,ypos:number,radius:number,color:any,
            text:string,speed:number,window_height:number,window_width:number,
            context:any, hit_counter:number){
      this.xpos=xpos;
      this.ypos=ypos;
      this.radius=radius;
      this.color=color;
      this.text=text;
      this.speed=speed;

      this.window_height=window_height;
      this.window_width=window_width;

      this.context=context;
      this.hit_counter=hit_counter;

      this.dx=1*this.speed;
      this.dy=1*this.speed;
  }

  draw(context:any){
      context.beginPath();

      context.strokeStyle=this.color;
      context.textAlign="center";
      context.textBaseline="middle";
      context.font="20px Arial";
      context.fillText(this.text,this.xpos,this.ypos);
      //context.strokeText(this.text,this.xpos,this.ypos);

      context.lineWidth=5;
      context.arc(this.xpos,this.ypos,this.radius,0,Math.PI*2,false);
      context.stroke();
      context.closePath();
  }

  update(){
      this.text=String(this.hit_counter);
      
      this.draw(this.context);
      if((this.xpos+this.radius)>this.window_width!){
          this.dx=-this.dx;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }

      if((this.xpos-this.radius)<0){
          this.dx=-this.dx;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }

      if((this.ypos-this.radius)<0){
          this.dy=-this.dy;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }

      if((this.ypos+this.radius)>this.window_height!){
          this.dy=-this.dy;
          this.hit_counter++;
      }

      this.xpos+=this.dx;
      this.ypos+=this.dy;
  }
}
```